# selenium webdriver get from partial url in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get driver.get from a partial url so for example:
usually we do this:

```
driver.get('www.dummy.com/event/rocknroll/1234')
```

but now I dont know the event name so is there any way I can do something like this:

```
 driver.get('www.dummy.com/event/*/1234')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this will not work, as the `get` method expects a string as the parameter.

From docs,

```
void get(String url);

  /**
   * Get a string representing the current URL that the browser is looking at.
   *
   * @return The URL of the page currently loaded in the browser
   */
```

However, have you tried hitting the url with some dummy tests for this?